# javascript executes wrong function

Tags: javascript, html, function

as you can tell, I'm having trouble having my javascript to execute the correct function(don't laugh). Here is what I am talking about: http://thomaswd.com/Chopsticks. when you drag the bottom left image to the top left like 5 times, the image grays out for one second and refreshes. When you do that to the other side, it executes the function for the left side instead. I tried firebug and safari error log, but they are no help at all. Please help!!!

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code? Also, http://www.whathaveyoutried.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function refreshRightCpu() {
    cpuLeftImg.src = "images/left-1.png";
    cpuRight = 1;
}
```

Shouldn't that be `cpuRightImg.src`?